# Smarty prints tag data outside html element

Tags: php, content-management-system, smarty, cmsmadesimple

I am working on a CMS Made Simple site. From an action I assign a variable to smarty:

```
$smarty->assign('anekdot', $row['anekdot']);
```

Then in the template I have:

```
<h2>АНЕКДОТ</h2>
<hr class="separator"/>
<p id="anekdot-text">{$anekdot}</p>
...
```

The strange thing is that the variable is printed **outside** of the `<p>` tag:
(I don't have reputation to post images, so here is external link)
http://oi62.tinypic.com/29564ch.jpg

As you can see the `<p>` tag is empty!!! And the content of `$anekdot` is printed beneath. Please, help :) Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the contents of $anekdot contains the problem. A mismatch in the p tags and the browser is trying to auto-correct the issue.

Comment: @Boreded, you are right. I can't put `<p>` in `<p>`. Thank you.